# Zeos and/or SQLite crashing with Memo

Tags: delphi, zeos

I have a VARCHAR2 Field of 10,000 Bytes and during the initiating process Zeos crashes with invalid data size. Stepping through it, the Size in question, Zeos shows 4,223,943 which I would agree, should be invalid.

Currently it appears that SQLite will not store more than 255 Bytes in a memo and now Zeos will not let me have a 10,000 VARCHAR2.

I tried with 5000 and it worked OK, but I needed more.

Should I look at something other than SQLite?

Thoughts and suggestions please.

Thanks (using D5)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement used to create a similar table. It would be helpful if we knew what you meant by "initiating process", the **exact** error message you're getting, and what you're "stepping through** and exactly what "Size in question" is referencing. "Should I look at something other than SQLite?" is also not an answerable question here - what *you* should look at is your decision to make. We can try and help you solve this problem, but not until you clearly tell us what it is first. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Just for information: AFAIK in SQLite3, the CREATE TABLE statement defines only some ["column affinity"](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), no exact type. You can put and read in fact any kind of data to/from a SQLIte3 column. And in SQLite3, TEXT columns have no size limit: CHAR 10, VARCHAR2 10000 or CLOB are in fact interpreted as TEXT, i.e. unlimited Unicode chars. With no speed penalty. In fact, in modern hardware, using fixed-size records is a space waste and a performance penalty - today's HW is not the same as the dBase/Paradox's time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the limitation of TDataset and its descendants, see dsMaxStringSize=8192. You cannot use (VAR)CHAR datatype. Sqlite itself keeps strings as ASCIIZ of 'unlimited' length.

Comment: ... so if the OP set the column type as `ftMemo`, it should work.

Comment: @pf1957 - Thanks, some actual Help! Now I understand why 5,000 worked and 10,000 did not. I was going to sneak up on it from 5K, but thanks to your 8192, I know where the limit is. - Arnaud, SQLite truncates the text at 255 for a ftMemo. I had already tried that and that's why I tried VARCHAR2. Looking through the available data types there is BLOB_TEXT which I am guessing is what I want to store a text document. -- Thanks to the ones who helped. :) Now I need to find out if Zeos will handle BLOB_TEXT.

Comment: Changing it to BLOB_TEXT solved the problem and Zeos handled the BLOB functions transparently to me and presented clean text in the DBMemo on reading records. Same for on saving new records, it handled all of the conversion to BLOB format.